# Python date range within 12 months

Tags: pandas, date-range

I want to create a new column if survey_start date is with 12 months **prior** to start_date then 1 else 0

| ID | survey_date | start_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-05-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 1 | 2021-12-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 2 | 2010-01-01 | 2010-02-01 |
| 2 | 2011-05-01 | 2010-02-01 |

output

| ID | survey_date | start_date | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-05-01 | 2022-05-01 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-05-01 | 2022-05-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-05-01 | 2022-05-01 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-12-01 | 2022-05-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2010-01-01 | 2010-02-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2011-05-01 | 2010-02-01 | 0 |

How do I do this in pandas dataframe?

Comment: Months (and years) do not always have the same number of days. How do you intend to adjust months?

Comment: I need without the day count. If its same date as previous year then want to flag it as 1 in 12 months period.

Comment: @Daven1, did the solution below worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it using np.where

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(((df['start_date'].astype('datetime64') - df['survey_date'].astype('datetime64') ).dt.days).between(0,366),1, 0)
df
```

```
    ID  survey_date     start_date  new_col
0   1   2019-05-01      2022-05-01   0
1   1   2021-05-01      2022-05-01   1
2   1   2023-05-01      2022-05-01   0
3   1   2021-12-01      2022-05-01   1
4   2   2010-01-01      2010-02-01   1
5   2   2011-05-01      2010-02-01   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`relativedelta`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)?

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import *

df['survey_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['survey_date'])
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['new column'] = df.apply(lambda x: relativedelta(x['start_date'], x['survey_date']), axis=1)
df['new column'] = df['new column'].apply(lambda x: 12*x.years + x.months)
df['new column'] = df['new column'].apply(lambda x: 1 if (x <= 12) & (x >= 0) else 0)
```

print(df):

```
   ID survey_date start_date  new column
0   1  2019-05-01 2022-05-01           0
1   1  2021-05-01 2022-05-01           1
2   1  2023-05-01 2022-05-01           0
3   1  2021-12-01 2022-05-01           1
4   2  2010-01-01 2010-02-01           1
5   2  2011-05-01 2010-02-01           0
```